# Type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

components/UI/Icon:

types.ts File:

```
export interface IIcon {
  iconName: string;
  iconSize: string;
  iconFill: string;
}
```

index.tsx File:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { IIcon } from './types';

export const Icon: FC<IIcon> = ({ iconName, iconSize, iconFill }) => {
  switch (iconName) {
    case 'logo':
      return (
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 64 64"
          enable-background="new 0 0 64 64"
          width={iconSize}
          height={iconSize}
        >
          <path
            d="m32 2c-16.568 0-30 13.432-30 30s13.432 30 30 30 30-13.432 30-30-13.432-30-30-30m6.016 44.508l-8.939-12.666-2.922 2.961v9.705h-5.963v-29.016h5.963v11.955l11.211-11.955h7.836l-11.909 11.934 12.518 17.082h-7.795"
            fill={iconFill}
          />
          <path
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            d="m32 2c-16.568 0-30 13.432-30 30s13.432 30 30 30 30-13.432 30-30-13.432-30-30-30m6.016 44.508l-8.939-12.666-2.922 2.961v9.705h-5.963v-29.016h5.963v11.955l11.211-11.955h7.836l-11.909 11.934 12.518 17.082h-7.795"
            fill={iconFill}
          />
        </svg>
      );
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

And after I have this this error:

```
Type '({ iconName, iconSize, iconFill }: IIcon) => Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FC<IIcon>'.
  Type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.ts(2322)
```

*Before that project i had experience only with jsx, and now I start lern a typescript and have very few experience with typescript*

Who have any suggestions?

Comment: It seems like you are missing a return statement for the default case of your switch. You need to either return some markup or null. undefined is not allowed as the return type, which is the default return value of a function without an explicit return. Try adding a return null (or what fits you) and see if that improves the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing returned in the `default` case of the `switch`, so the return of the function is effectively `Element | undefined`.

But with `const Icon: FC<IIcon>`, you're telling Typescript that the type of `Icon` is `FC<IIcon>`.
If you have a look to the typing of `FC` (F12 in Visual Studio Code for example), you'll see that:

```
    type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;

    interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
        (props: P, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
        propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined;
        contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined;
        defaultProps?: Partial<P> | undefined;
        displayName?: string | undefined;
    }
```

The first line of the `FunctionComponent` interface specifies that the interface is a [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types), that takes a `props: P` and a `context?: any`, and returns **`ReactElement<any, any> | null`**.

Back to the error: your component return `Element | undefined`, which do not match the interface, since `undefined` is not assignable to `ReactElement<any, any> | null`.
Adding a `return null` in the default case of the switch will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just return `React.Fragment` or - `<></>` which is the same:

```
...
  default:
    return <></>
...
```